# Need to find a way to modify series values of a chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FormatSpecificChartSeries()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim chtName As String
    Dim seriesName As String
    Dim levelChoice As Integer
    Dim multiplier As Double
    Dim currencySymbol As String
    Dim levelSymbol As String
    Dim decimalPlaces As Integer
    Dim series As series
    Dim point As point

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    chtName = InputBox("Enter the name of the chart:")
    If chtName = "" Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(chtName).Chart
    On Error GoTo 0
    If cht Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Chart not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    seriesName = InputBox("Enter the name of the series:")
    If seriesName = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set series = Nothing
    For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
        If s.Name = seriesName Then
            Set series = s
            Exit For
        End If
    Next s
    
    If series Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Series not found in the specified chart."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    levelChoice = Application.InputBox("Select a Level:" & vbCrLf & _
                                       "1: Thousand" & vbCrLf & _
                                       "2: Million" & vbCrLf & _
                                       "3: Billion", Type:=1)
    
    Select Case levelChoice
        Case 1
            multiplier = 1000
            levelSymbol = "K"
        Case 2
            multiplier = 1000000
            levelSymbol = "MM"
        Case 3
            multiplier = 1000000000
            levelSymbol = "B"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid level selection."
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    For Each point In series.Points
        If IsNumeric(point.DataLabel.Text) Then
            Dim originalValue As Double
            originalValue = CDbl(point.DataLabel.Text)
            Dim newValue As Double
            newValue = originalValue / multiplier
            point.DataLabel.Text = currencySymbol & Format(newValue, "0." & String(decimalPlaces, "0")) & " " & levelSymbol
                        series.Values(point.Index) = newValue
        End If
    Next point
End Sub
```

In the above code, the program will ask the name of the chart, the name of the series and can then modify the data labels in a clean way to present in a ppt, but I also want the axis to reflect the modified value, say I'm converting 2000000 to $2M, the axis should show 2, not 2000000

But this line:

`series.Values(point.Index) = newValue`

I put the above line in an endeavor to modify the series values with modified values, but it results in an error: 'object doesn't support the property or method'. Any ideas?

I expected the code to change the axis values.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate the Category axis values, it can be done with the whole values as an array or a Range. savearr is an array of the axis values which, after modification are restored to the Chart.

```
 savearr = cht.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames
 pointer = 0
 For Each Point In Series.Points
         pointer = pointer + 1
         If IsNumeric(Point.DataLabel.text) Then
            Dim originalValue As Double
            originalValue = CDbl(Point.DataLabel.text)
            Dim newValue As Double
            newValue = originalValue / multiplier
            Point.DataLabel.text = currencySymbol & Format(newValue, "0." & String(DecimalPlaces, "0")) & " " & levelSymbol
                        'series.Values(point.Index) = newValue
                         savearr(pointer) = newValue
        End If
    Next Point
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = savearr
```

For the Y (Values) Axis

```
For Each Point In Series.Points
        If IsNumeric(Point.DataLabel.text) Then
            Dim originalValue As Double
            originalValue = CDbl(Point.DataLabel.text)
            Dim newValue As Double
            newValue = originalValue / multiplier
            Point.DataLabel.text = currencySymbol & Format(newValue, "0." & String(DecimalPlaces, "0")) & " " & levelSymbol
                        'series.Values(point.Index) = newValue
        End If
Next Point
    cht.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = -WorksheetFunction.Log10(multiplier)
    cht.Axes(xlValue).HasDisplayUnitLabel = True
```

Comment: Yes, not `s` but `cht` the chart. changed in the answer too

Comment: This code is working perfectly! Except its modifying the X axis, I need to modify the Y Axis

Comment: @mikey6136 Added the code for the Y axis.